# Swapping the order of a sum and a derivative

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

We define the following infinite sum with a parameter $t \in \mathbb{R}$, and $t>0$, and assume $x \in \mathbb{R},$
\begin{equation}
u(x,t)\triangleq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{h^{(k)}(t)}{(2k)!}x^{2k},
\end{equation}
here $h^{(k)}(t)$ is the k-th derivative of a smooth enough function $h(t)$ and satisfies the estimate $| h^{(k)}(t) | \leq \frac{k!}{t^k}e^{-t^{-\alpha}}, \alpha>1$ is a given constant.

I want to prove that
\begin{equation}
\partial_t u(x,t)\triangleq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{h^{(k+1)}(t)}{(2k)!}x^{2k},\ \partial_x u(x,t)\triangleq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{h^{(k)}(t)}{(2k-1)!}x^{2k-1},
\end{equation}
that is, the sum and derivative respect to $x$ and $t$ can be interchanged.

For fixed $t$, $u(x,t)$ is a series with respect to $x$, the convergence of the power series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{h^{(k)}(t)}{(2k)!}x^{2k}$ is infinity, so we can swap the derivative with respect to $x$ and the sum. However, for the $\partial_t u$ case, it is not power series with respect to $t$, so I don't know how to do. Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: For $\partial_x u$ it's a power series in $x$, so it's automatic if all the $u(\cdot,t)$ were able to be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$. As for $\partial_t u$, what do you mean by it not being a series in regard to $t$? With the estimates you have on the derivatives of $h$, you may want to go for differentiation under the sum sign instead of uniform convergence.

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much.